# it says printing job is done, but nothing printed

Tags: printing, canon

help.
I have my Canon LBP-2900B connected to my laptop successfully. when I start printing, it says that printing job is going and completed, but printer itself didn't do anything at all.

Comment: Have you installed printer drivers? Is the computer identifying the printer?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Linux 32/64bit(depending on your pc) canon driver v2.71 from https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/printers/laser/i-sensys_lbp2900.html?type=drivers&driverdetailid=tcm:13-1057853&os=linux%20%2864-bit%29&language=en
2. Go to you where you downloaded your driver. Type: tar -xf linux-capt-drv-v271-uken.tar.gz
3. Then type: cd linux-capt-drv-v271-uken/64-bit_Driver/Debian/
4. Then type  sudo dpkg -i cndrvcups-capt_2.71-1_amd64.deb
5. Put in your user password
6. Reboot your pc